# Compressing mp3s that contain mostly silence

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, mp3, audio-recording

I am looking for the optimal way to compress a large mp3 that contains >80% silence. It seems like mp3s consume nearly the same amount of space for a given duration independent of the content of the file. Are there any other compression formats that would do a better job of reducing the file size without significantly affecting quality of the non-silent parts?

Comment: Share full command and log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any lossy codec in this mode (MP3 included), be sure you're encoding with variable bitrate (VBR).  If you use a constant bitrate (CBR), the codec is going to output a (mostly) constate rate of data regardless of what the input was.

Without knowing more about the problem you're trying to solve, it's hard to give a specific solution.  The best generally available codec these days is Opus, but it isn't the most compatible.  AAC is also quite good and is widely compatible.  If you have true digital silence, FLAC takes up zero bandwidth during silent parts.  It's lossless though, and naturally requires a lot of bandwidth during the non-silent parts.